# Spark Dataframe giving different levels of precision for floats

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, precision

As we are creating a spark dataframe we send the data in the dataframe into Kudu and Kafka(which in turns gets picked up and goes into S3)

However, the precision from what we see in Kudu once dataframe is upserted is 1e-15 
[image: Kudu Precision]

Now if I use that same dataframe and convert it to a format that Kafka can use

```
override def getKafkaDataFrame(df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
df.withColumn("key", to_json(struct(df.col(PK1),
  df.col(PK2)))
  .withColumn("value", to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*)))
```

which in turn (in a seperate app) sends to S3

It turns out like this for the same row which is 1e-6

[image: S3 Precision]

We also have a method from going to Kudu to S3 directly (ableit not a stream) and that precision is matching Kudu when inferSchema is set to true and then a simple dataframe.write

Im wondering where this loss of precision/scale is coming from and how do I go about fixing it.

Whats been attempted:
Casting all fields as String,
Casting only the float fields to doubles

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what datasource was used for a dataframe but most probably problem is caused by schema and data type for a column with the precision issue. [FloatType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference.html#data-types) isn't enough to handle 1e-15 precision since it represents 4-byte single-precision floating point numbers.

Small example

```
object DecisionPlays {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types.FloatType

  case class DoubleColumn(doubleValue:Double)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val temp = DoubleColumn(1.12345678910111213)
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(temp))
    //[1.1234567891011122,{"doubleValue":1.1234567891011122}]
    df.withColumn("value", to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*))).collect().foreach(println)
    //[1.1234568,{"doubleValue":1.1234568}]
    df.select(col("doubleValue").cast(FloatType))
      .withColumn("value", to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*))).collect().foreach(println)

  }
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, when I do printSchema, it says that column is a float. So clearly it doesnt change when we send it to Kudu, which confuses me why I try to cast it to a double it is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

Taking what Andrey said about spark floats

I decided to make a single field that was a float and change it to a double everywhere in the code

And it worked!

Kudu already changes all floats to doubles so no data changed happened there but now the data is proper in s3 as well